# how to interact with telegram bot scene in chat?

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram

I made a bot which gets added to chat, on command the bot entering to scene in chat, but after first step it stop interacts.

What is the problem and how to fix it?

```
const createPayment = new Scenes.WizardScene(
  "createPayment",
  async (ctx) => {
    ctx.session.myData = {};
    await ctx.reply("");
    return ctx.wizard.next();
  },
  async (ctx) => {
    ctx.session.myData.requisites = ctx.message.text;
    await ctx.reply("");
    return ctx.wizard.next();
  },
  async (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply("");
    return ctx.wizard.leave();
  }
);

const stage = new Scenes.Stage([createPayment]);

bot.use(session());
bot.use(stage.middleware());

bot.command("test", async (ctx) => {
  await ctx.scene.enter("createPayment");
});
```